# Is there for the bash something like perls __DATA__?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there for the bash something like perls `__DATA__`? 
I mean the feature, that the code after `__DATA__` will not be executed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Shell scripts are parsed on a line-by-line basis as they execute, so you just need to ensure execution never reaches the data you want to protect. You could do this, for instance:

```
# Some shell code...

exit

[data (possibly binary) goes here]
```

To actually *read* this data from your script, you can use some sed magic to extract everything after the first line containing only `__DATA__`, then store the output of that sed in a variable. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/sh

data=$(sed '0,/^__DATA__$/d' "$0")
printf '%s\n' "$data"

exit

__DATA__
FOO BAR BAZ
LLAMA DUCK COW
```

If you save this script as `test-data.sh` and make it executable, you can run it and get the following output:

```
$ ./test-data.sh
FOO BAR BAZ
LLAMA DUCK COW
```

Comment: this is cool, can someone please explain how this works? I didn't understand the `data=$(sed '0,/^__DATA__$/d' "$0")`

Comment: Run the `sed` command and from line 0 to the line that matches __DATA__, delete the line. The rest will print. $0 is this script, the file to read that contains the data.

Comment: Careful, though; if you are sourcing in your script, not just running it, then `$0` is your shell name and your `exit` will exit your entire session. Replace `$0` with `${BASH_ARGV[0]}` and `exit` with `return`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all perl's "__DATA__" pragma is a way of supplying input to $_ without specifying a file.  There is no equivalent in bash since it has nothing similar to $_.  However you can supply data directly in a bash script by other means such as explicit setting variables, using HERE docs etc.

However I'm not convinced this is what you wish to do.  It seems your after some sort of block commenting method.  Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, but the other part is interesting too. 
So I will accept the exit solution though it is not as nice as __DATA__ because after __DATA__ there is no more syntax-highlighting and __DATA__ itself is more visible in the code than exit. For supplying data I would probably us a HERE doc since it is easier to remember than bcat's proposal.

Comment: Yes, using a heredoc is almost certainly the best solution for supplying large amounts of data to a script. The only time I'd use my solution (other than as a proof of concept) is if I needed the ability to easily include data in a shell script that could possibly include the heredoc terminator.

Comment: IIUC, explicitly setting variables and using heredocs will have the effect of having your data right smack dab in the middle of your code. The __DATA__ technique will put all that data at the end so that you can read code without the context interrupt.

IMO, using this for data is NOT optimal. Better to read from an external source. BUT, it might be appropriate for a self-documenting test. I only use it for USAGE statements as above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful technique if you want to provide usage info for your script, but do not want to clutter up the main line of code with the help text. It's also great if you want to reference the usage more than once. To wit, a snippet from a shell script of mine:

```
...
declare OPTSARGS    
OPTSARGS=$(getoptp -o wh --long nopager,help -n myScript-- "$@")
status=$? 
if ((status != 0))    
then
    printf '%s\n' "$(sed '0,/^__USAGE__$/d' $0)"
    exit $status
fi
eval set -- "$OPTSARGS"  
while true
do
    case "$1" in
        -w) diffargs="$diffargs -w"; shift;;
        --nopager) pager=cat; shift;;
        --) shift; break ;; ## end of opts, remaining $*, if any, are args
        -h | --help)
            printf '%s\n' "$(sed '0,/^__USAGE__$/d' $0)"
            exit 0;;
        *)
            echo "Internal error!"
            printf '%s\n' "$(sed '0,/^__USAGE__$/d' $0)"
            exit 1;;
   esac
done

...

echo "Done"
exit 0

__USAGE__
myScript [-w] [--nopager] [file [file...] ]

Some description goes here.

       -w - Do not compare whitespace
--nopager - Do not pass the output through 'less'
```